# chatting by socket and C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I did an application of chat with socket:
the server create a socket connection and wait message from any client 
for Server:

```
           using System;
           using System.Collections.Generic;
           using System.ComponentModel;
           using System.Data;
           using System.Drawing;
           using System.Linq;
           using System.Text;
           using System.Windows.Forms;
            using System.Xml;
           using System.Net.Sockets;
           using System.Net;
            using System.Threading;
            using System.IO;
          namespace server
        {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static byte[] data;
    public static byte[] data1;
    public static Socket sock;
    public delegate void operation(string s);
    public delegate void operation2();
    public delegate bool verifier();
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPAddress adress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(adress, 4000);
        EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
        sock.Bind(iep);
        sock.Listen(10);
        sock = sock.Accept();
        data1 = new byte[1024];
        data = new byte[1024];
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        this.Show();
        if (sock.Receive(data) > 0)
      {

          Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(aller));
          t.Start();

      }




    }

    private void effectuer(String s)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "serveur:  " + s + "\r\n";

        message.Text  = "";
    }
    private void effectuer4(String s)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "Client:  " + s + "\r\n";

        message.Text = "";
    }

    private void aller() {


        String  s = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

        if (this.InvokeRequired) Invoke((operation)effectuer4, s);
        else effectuer4(s);
       //Thread.Sleep(2000);
        byte[] data2 = new byte[1024];

            if (sock.Receive(data2) > 0 && data2 != data)
            {
                data = data2;
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(aller));
                t.Start();
            }

        }


    private void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sock.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String s = message.Text ;
        data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

        sock.Send(data1);

        Invoke((operation)effectuer, s);


    }
    }

}
```

For client : he send an empty message to server and wait for the response of server

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Net.Sockets;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Xml;


    namespace client
    {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
    public static TcpClient SocketPourClient = null;
    public static string ClientMessage;
    public static string ServerMessage;
    Socket sock;
    public static byte[] data;
    public static byte[] data1;
    public delegate void operation(String s);
    public delegate void lancer();
    public delegate bool verifier();

    public Form1(string ip, int port)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
               IPAddress adress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(adress, 4000);
              sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    sock.Connect(ipEnd);
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    sock.Close();

                }
                 Thread t1 = new Thread(envoi);
                   t1.Start();
                    data = new byte[1024];
                    if (sock.Receive(data) > 0)
                {

                    Thread t=new Thread(new ThreadStart(aller));
                    t.Start();
                }

    }

    private void aller()
    {

        String s = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

           if(this.InvokeRequired) Invoke((operation)effectuer4, s);
        else effectuer4(s);
          //  Thread.Sleep(2000);
            byte[] data2 = new byte[1024];

                if (sock.Receive(data2) > 0 && data2 != data)
                {
                    data = data2;
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(aller));
                    t.Start();
                }
      }

    private void envoi()
    {
       String s = message.Text ;
        data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        sock.Send(data1);
        effectuer(s);


    }



private void effectuer(String s)
{
    textBox1.Text += "client:  " + s + "\r\n";

    message.Text = "";
}

 private void effectuer4(String s)
 {
     textBox1.Text += "Server:  " + s + "\r\n";

     message.Text = "";

 }

private void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sock.Close();
    Application.Exit();
}

private void buttonSend_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String s = message.Text ;
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    sock.Send(data1);
    Invoke((operation)effectuer, s);


   }



}
```

}

my problems are:
i won't that the server or client will be not obliged to initialise the application but twice can do it + when i did the server as a console application it works but when i changes the server to winforms like that the application is blocked!!!!!! So i need help

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the listen/accept loop in the Form1 ctor!!

Run the listen/accept in a separate listening thread.

Comment: i add this code :     Thread lis = new                     Thread(listenning);
 lis.Start();  and i make the listen/accept in this thread but an exception for unabilitity to send when socket is disconnect appears

Comment: thanks Martin i solved this problem of threads. i need now how to make my application interactif : like you saw the client must initialise the chat , i won't that the server and the client can initialise the application like a normal chat